# Can't access to subfolder on my domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdirectory

I have a problem. I've installed a wordpress website on a subfolder of my personal website (plain HTML). When I try to access to the subfolder I get an Internal Server Error. 
I haven't any .htaccess for the moment on my website root and the default Wordpress one on the subfolder.
I never had a problem like this.
What can I do ?

Thank you !

Comment: There's something wrong with your WP installation. Surely. Do you have access to the server/php log?

Comment: Hi jtherman, thank you for your answer. No, I havent access to that, however I put a local wp installation on the subfolder. I've checked the configuration.php without finding any problem (I've modified it as I uploaded the website on remote server)

Comment: Are you sure there is no .htaccess file in the subfolder of your WP installation? There might be some syntax error in the file(s) you modified...